# AWS Lambda Blank Function not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to aws lambda. I am trying to create a new custom function. 
But under my aws blueprint, there is no "Blank Function" option available.

Comment: Read following article series for AWS lambda:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/aws-lambda-and-serverless-computing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on `Author from Scratch` to create Blank Function.

[image: BulePrint ScreenShot]